# VB winforms custom control zoom and pan functionality?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, gdi+

I'm currently making a node diagram control for Winforms, the control contains nodes which is basically just an "empty" class with properties, so the nodes are drawn in the control and the control handles them.

My control needs to support zooming and panning. Currently I'm zooming by using the Graphics.ScaleTransform method, and panning by using AutoScroll.

The two work great by themselves, but using them together doesn't work.

To make panning "better", I have hidden the scrollbars, set the AutoScrollMinSize to 9000 and centered the AutoScrollPosition (4500). So that it hopefully feels like you have a canvas to work on, so that you can go any direction that you'd like.

That works quite well, however when zooming (ScaleTransform), the nodes will be moved x amount to the left top corner of the form (if zooming out) or to the right bottom corner (if zooming in).

Youtube video of problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJBAHtNhung

So due to text length issues here on stackoverflow, I'm not quite able to post all the code, so I'll just try to post the relevant stuff (which I guess I should do anyway).

Custom control OnPaint:

```
    G.TranslateTransform(AutoScrollPosition.X, AutoScrollPosition.Y)

    G.ScaleTransform(Zoom, Zoom)

    'Draw grid
    If ShowGrid Then
        Using Pen As New Pen(GridColor.ToBrush())
            For row As Integer = 0 To viewportRect.Right Step GridSize.Width
                G.DrawLine(Pen, New Point(row, 0), New Point(row, 0 + viewportRect.Bottom))
            Next

            For col As Integer = 0 To viewportRect.Bottom Step GridSize.Height
                G.DrawLine(Pen, New Point(0, col), New Point(0 + viewportRect.Right, col))
            Next
        End Using
    End If

    'Draw connections
    For Each Connection As Connection In Connections
        Connection.Draw(G)
    Next

    'Draw all the nodes
    For Each Node As Node In Nodes
        Node.Draw(G)
    Next

    'Draw the active tool (Multi select or NodeLinker)
    If ActiveTool IsNot Nothing Then
        ActiveTool.OnDraw(G)
    End If
```

Zoom:

```
If e.Delta < 0 Then
    NodeContainer.Zoom -= 0.1F
Else
    NodeContainer.Zoom += 0.1F
End If
```

Pan:

```
  If Panning Then
            Delta = New Point(StartPoint.X - e.X, StartPoint.Y - e.Y)
            NodeContainer.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Delta.X - NodeContainer.AutoScrollPosition.X, Delta.Y - NodeContainer.AutoScrollPosition.Y)
        End If
```

How would I got about solving this, or should I be going about this a different way (maybe draw an image instead, and then reposition that image, etc.)?

Comment: The usualy way is to use two Panels, the outer  one (Parent) is autoscrolling, and on the inner one (nested) you draw. Often the inner one is a PictureBox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to remove autoscrolling, then relocate all the nodes whenever zooming or panning occurs.

Zoom:

```
oldZoom = NodeContainer.Zoom

If e.Delta < 0 Then
    NodeContainer.Zoom = Math.Max(NodeContainer.Zoom - 0.1F, 0.01F)
Else
    NodeContainer.Zoom = Math.Min(NodeContainer.Zoom + 0.1F, 10.0F)
End If

For Each Node As Node In NodeContainer.Nodes
    oldZoomLocation = New Point(e.X / oldZoom, e.Y / oldZoom)
    newZoomLocation = New Point(e.X / NodeContainer.Zoom, e.Y / NodeContainer.Zoom)

    Node.Location = New Point(newZoomLocation.X - oldZoomLocation.X + Node.Location.X, newZoomLocation.Y - oldZoomLocation.Y + Node.Location.Y)
Next
```

Pan:

```
Delta = New Point(e.X - StartPoint.X, e.Y - StartPoint.Y)

For Each Node As Node In NodeContainer.Nodes
    Node.Location = New Point(Node.Location.X + (Delta.X / NodeContainer.Zoom), Node.Location.Y + (Delta.Y / NodeContainer.Zoom))
Next

StartPoint = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
```